# Is there anyway to save a multiple buttons as a list?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making small restaurant system project. I have 16 buttons as tables in the restaurant. I would like to change their colors or disable any of them when some events trigger (the form is loaded).

I save my button names in format `TableX_ButtonY`

I used a for-loop to change theirs border colors like this:

```
CType(Me.Controls.Find(String.Format("Table{0}Button{1}", i, x), True)(0), Button).FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Blue
```

It will be great if I can save these buttons as a list, so I can manage it more easily.

I name their tags from 1 to 16 but I don't know how to use them correctly. Because the trigger not based on button click but rather based on the Load Form event.

Comment: You'll have to put them in a list yourself when the application loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Dim TableList As New List(Of Button) 

 TableList.Add(TableX_ButtonY)


 For Each Table As Button in TableList
     'do stuff
 next
```

if you generated the buttons by using the designer, you can use the method you described in your question to add them all to the list

Answer (score 2):

Buttons are already in a collection and is a bit redundant to add them to a generic collection. In this example there are 2 buttons in a group controls collection, which could very well be any applicable container.

```
    Dim ReservedTables() As Integer = {5, 10, 15, 20}

    For Each Btn As Button In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
        If ReservedTables.Contains(CType(Btn.Tag, Integer)) Then
            Btn.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I'll save this as a note. I am so lazy to change my code since it's working. But I think this is viable option to make my code cleaner.

Comment: No worries, note the usage of the tag property. This property is an object(I believe) meaning it should be able to hold anything really, so you have to cast it out accordingly.